# Resources$NotFoundException at chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle.aab-stable

Tags: android, crash, chromium, motorola

Recently, a significant number of WebView-related crashes were discovered on Crashlytics, primarily occurring on Motorola devices running the Android 12 system. Has anyone encountered a similar issue?

The stack trace is as follows:

```
Fatal Exception: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x2100004
    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue(ResourcesImpl.java:233)
    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.openRawResource(ResourcesImpl.java:348)
    at android.content.res.Resources.openRawResource(Resources.java:1378)
    at android.content.res.Resources.openRawResource(Resources.java:1322)
    at WV.Tr.<init>(chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle.aab-stable-599311131:12)
    at WV.oC.<init>(chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle.aab-stable-599311131:18)
    at org.chromium.android_webview.AwBrowserProcess.g(chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle.aab-stable-599311131:91)
    at com.android.webview.chromium.M.e(chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle.aab-stable-599311131:208)
    at WV.SY.run(chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle.aab-stable-599311131:8)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:978)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:238)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:357)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8090)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1026)
```

From the stack trace, it appears to be primarily occurring within the Chrome kernel source code. It is hoped that there is a way to mitigate the corresponding issue.

Comment: Any resolution?

Comment: @ArunkarthickNallasami not yet

Comment: Hi! I'm having also this issue. Do we have any updates?